# How to display data in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have just gotten started with datatables and I was working with this example from the datatables docs, but I can't get the data to display .
This is the `.html file`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>data</title>
<script   href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script   href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": 'arrays.txt'
} );
} );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the `arrays.txt` file:

```
    {
      "data": [

    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ]
]
}
```

The problem is that no data is displayed in the datatable.

Comment: try putting it in a `PRE` instead of the table for debugging. The `arrays.txt` seems to be missing a closing square bracket before the closing curly bracket!

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: @EliasSoares I get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `datatable` before `jquery`.

Since `datatable` requires `jQuery`, you must load `jQuery` first.

Also you should never import scripts on head. Put it on the end of your body tag, before the script tags.